# Programatically-Set Hint Field Reverts to Old Value when Soft Keyboard Up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have either a numeric or alpha EditText, switched by a toggle, which also changes the hint in the field.  The methods setHint and setInputType are used to do this from the toggle's onClick method.

When the toggle is clicked, the hint changes properly.  The keyboard-type which is raised upon clicking in the EditText also changes properly.  But when the soft keyboard is raised, the hint reverts to its original value.  If I close the soft keyboard, the hint goes back to the "correct" value, as it appeared before the soft-keyboard raised.

Is this a known bug, or is there a workaround?

Note:  I am using the Eclipse / ADT Emulator for testing; Platform 4.1.2 - Intelx86.

Edit: I just noticed that the values are always reversed.  In other words "Hint 1" shows up with no soft-keyboard (correct value), then "Hint 2" with soft keyboard.  If I hit the toggle, the reverse is true - "Hint 2" shows up without soft keyboard (correct value), then "Hint 1" with soft-keyboard.  Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this problem and reported it as a bug to AOSP, attaching a sample project: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170596

There doesn't seem to be any easy workaround for now.